# How do I access *.xq4 and *.xq5 suffix files?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql, btrieve

For a project I am required to access the data stored by the program. The software writes the data to respectively a *.xq4-file and a *.xq5-file. I would like to access or extract the data from the files. What tool should I use to open these file types?

Comment: What is the software application that writes to these file types? Do the xq files contain the XQuery expressions or the results of running those expression against an XML source file? Presumably the content of the files is text-based, so can you not open them with a text editor or an editor designed specifically for working with XQuery (e.g. http://basex.org/)?

Comment: The software application is called "Exquise", with a Pervasive SQL engine (which I am not familiar with). Exquise is a software application for Dentists. The *.xq-files contain the results of running the expressions.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the content of one of these files?

Comment: Lines are structured the following way:
980000000000080001prestatM10       Fluoridebehandeling, methode I

Comment: [Exquise](https://www.vertimart.nl/producten-en-diensten/exquise) is (or was?), apparently, using [PSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pervasive_PSQL), which has the 'freedom' of choosing any extension for a datafile...